# Set django related model set and delete models no longer in set

Tags: django, django-models, models, django-related-manager

In the Django documentation, [it mentions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#direct-assignment) that when you directly specify the new related set, any models no longer in the set are simply disassociated instead of deleted.

In other words, if you have a situation like this:

```
#author.books contains [book1, book2, book3]
author.books = [book1, book2]
author.save()
```

The book 3 model is no longer associated with the author, but it is NOT deleted. Is there a way to disassociate AND delete the model?

Answer (score 0):

If `book3` is an model object, you would just run

```
book3.delete()
```

And it will disassociate it from the Author's books (if that is a Key or many-to-many key for example) because it is deleted.  And the record is also deleted from the Book model.

Comment: Well yes, but if I am being passed a new array of items to save, then the logic becomes a little overly verbose because I have to check for items no longer in the array. There's no automatic way?

Comment: Do you want to delete all books that don't belong to any author?  You can override the `save()` method in the `model`, but you would need some logic as to which books to delete.